# Codeigniter count_all for pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm trying to create pagination in codeigniter and I have it working, but I have a small issue. It seems to be loading all the entries in my database and not the selected ones I want.

```
public function original_count() {
     $this->db->where('type', 'Original');
      return $this->db->count_all("story_tbl");
    }
```

I know that whats happening is that the last line is overrighting my previous statements. I can't seem to find a way around it though. I tried just a staight sql statement and then returning it, but I could not get that to work either.

this was my statement...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM story_tbl where type = 'Original';
```

Some help would much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also use the built-in `num_rows()` function...

```
$query = $this->db->where('type', 'original')->get('story_tbl');
return $query->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 12):

CI has inbuilt count method

```
count_all_results()
```

**Permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular Active Record query. Queries will accept Active Record restrictors such as where(), or_where(), like(), or_like(), etc. Example:**

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

```
$total_count = $this->db->count_all_results('story_tbl', array('type' =>'Original'));
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had something like this...almost verbatim. It unfortunately didn't work for me. It kept throwing me an error telling me that I could not return ints. Fortunitly, the above answer solved me problem! :)

Answer (score 3):

First Try this one.

```
$query = $this->db->where('tbl_field', 'value')
         ->get('your_table');
return $query->num_rows();
```

Besides this Codeigniter has it own function like the following.

```
 $this->db->where('tbl_field', 'value')
             ->get('your_table');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Or use this.

```
return $this->db->count_all('your_table');
```

Answer (score 1):

`Where` wont work on count_all condition.. you can use below method to find out total number of rows..

```
public function count_all() {
    $this->db->select ( 'COUNT(*) AS `numrows`' );
    $this->db->where ( array (
            'type' => 'Original'
    ) );
    $query = $this->db->get ( 'story_tbl' );
    return $query->row ()->numrows;
}
```